# Python CSV output to columns from two lists

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, csv, export-to-csv

I'm grabbing search results from bing. Everything is working except the output to the csv file. I've tried pandas also but can't seem to get the output right. I need the "url" in column A and "name" in column B next to the corresponding link.

[example search link](https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F%20and%20%22mortgage%22%20and%20%22utah%22%20and%20%20%22slc%22&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F%20and%20%22mortgage%22%20and%20%22utah%22%20and%20%22slc%22&sc=0-57&sk=&cvid=ACFC3C8037D3470B80B3CFE4525835BD)

```
def scrape():
    urls = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "b_algo")))
    url = [div.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href') for div in urls]
    names = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "b_algo")))
    name = [div.find_element_by_tag_name('h2 > a').get_attribute('innerHTML').split('-')[0].strip() for div in names]

   x1 = [url]
   x2 = [name]

   pp.pprint([url,name])

   with open(bing_parameters.file_name, 'a', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       wr = csv.writer(f)
       for items in x1:
           wr.writerow([x1,x2])
scrape()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. To put url to the first column and name to second column and then write to csv.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(url)
df.columns =['A']
df['B']=name
print(df)
df.to_csv(bing_parameters.file_name, index=False)
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. How do I append to instead of overwrite with pandas?

Comment: df.to_csv(bing_parameters.file_name, mode='a', index=False)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this data:

```
x1 = ['foo']
x2 = ['https://www.example.com']
```

Then your existing code is doing something like this

```
for items in x1:
    print([x1, x2])
```

Giving this incorrect output:

```
[['foo'], ['https://www.example.com']]
```

The code is looping over the contents of `x1` - a list containing one item, so the loop will have one iteration - and outputting a list containing `x1` and `x2`, which are both lists.

If `x1` and `x2` are always single item lists you can explicitly select the first item in each, and dispense with the loop:

```
    with open(bing_parameters.file_name, 'a', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       wr = csv.writer(f)
       wr.writerow([x1[0], x2[0]])
```

or just not make these redundant lists

```
   with open(bing_parameters.file_name, 'a', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       wr = csv.writer(f)
       wr.writerow([name, url])
```

If `x1` and `x2` contain multiple corresponding items, you can [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them together:

```
x1 = [name1, name2]
x2 = [url1, url2]

   with open(bing_parameters.file_name, 'a', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       wr = csv.writer(f)
       for name, url in zip(x1, x2):
           wr.writerow([name, url])
```

or even

```
x1 = [name1, name2]
x2 = [url1, url2]

   with open(bing_parameters.file_name, 'a', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       wr = csv.writer(f)
       wr.writerows(zip(x1, x2))
```